# download facebook photos using graph API in JSON Format?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi using graph API i am able to get the photos of my albums, now i want to download all the photos in the album to my computer. it returns data in JSon format, how can i filter only the Urls of the images from that json and then download all photos from that url
my json is some like this format

```
{


"data": [
      {
         "id": "1140894483853",
         "from": {
            "name": "Muhammad Asghar",
            "id": "1272156814"
         },
         "tags": {
            "data": [
               {
                  "id": "1272156814",
                  "name": "Muhammad Asghar",
                  "x": 52.6,
                  "y": 29.538,
                  "created_time": "2009-08-20T07:46:50+0000"
               }
            ]
         },
         "picture": "http://photos-d.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v3356/171/103/1272156814/s1272156814_30392128_5890712.jpg",
         "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v3356/171/103/1272156814/n1272156814_30392128_5890712.jpg",
         "height": 604,
         "width": 498,
         "images": [
            {
               "height": 604,
               "width": 498,
               "source": "http://a4.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/photos-ak-snc1/v3356/171/103/1272156814/n1272156814_30392128_5890712.jpg"
            },
```

Please anyone help.

Comment: Try json_decode?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JsonDecode: [JsonDecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
assume your json string is in a `$data` variable, you can try something like this:

```
<?php
var_dump( json_decode($data));
?>
```

if you look at the source code of the page you'll have a pretty clear idea of how the json is structured, and you can easly use a foreach statement to get only the urls you need

Comment: please tell me how can i loop on this json to get all the values in source object